# Rails: How to find records where parent class is deleted?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I would like to search all the records of Courses that belong to a Category that no longer exists.

1. Course A is made under Category 1 (not dependent)
2. Course A now has foreign key category_id = 1
3. We delete Category 1
4. Course A still has category_id = 1, but that category no longer exists.

This becomes a problem because Course A will not show up when I do something like

```
Course.where(category_id:nil)
```

I realize I could probably delete the category_ids in all Courses that belong to that category right before I delete the category, but given that the category_id value still exists in Courses even after the parent Category is deleted, what would be the "correct" way to search for these homeless courses?

Answer (score 2):

If there are not too much categories, you may use this

```
Course.where.not(category_id: Category.pluck(:id))
```

Comment: If I recall correctly, `not` was added in `QueryMethods` in Rails 4.

Comment: I recall the same :) But that doesn't matter, you can hardcode "not" in Rails 3, `Course.where('category_id NOT IN', Category.pluck(:id))`.